# MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, sqlmodel

I am trying to get the number of rows matched in a one to many relationship. When I try `parent.children_count` I get :

> sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called;
> can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)

I added `expire_on_commit=False` but still get the same error. How can I fix this?

```py
import asyncio
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Relationship, Field
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession

class Parent(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4, primary_key=True)
    children: list["Child"] = Relationship(back_populates="parent")
    @property
    def children_count(self):
        return len(self.children)

class Child(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4, primary_key=True)
    parent_id: UUID = Field(default=None, foreign_key=Parent.id)
    parent: "Parent" = Relationship(back_populates="children")

async def main():
    engine = create_async_engine("sqlite+aiosqlite://")
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)

    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        parent = Parent()
        session.add(parent)
        await session.commit()
        await session.refresh(parent)
        print(parent.children_count)  # I expect 0 here, as of now this parent has no children

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the problem here is that by default SQLAlchemy lazy-loads relationships, so accessing `parent.children_count` implicitly triggers a database query leading to the reported error.

One way around this would be to specify a [load strategy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-techniques) other than "lazy" in the relationship definition.  Using SQLModel, this would look like:

```py
children: list['Child'] = Relationship(
    back_populates='parent', sa_relationship_kwargs={'lazy': 'selectin'}
)
```

This will cause SQLAlchemy to issue an additional query to fetch the relationship while still in "async mode".  Another option would be to pass `{'lazy': 'joined'}`, which would cause SQLAlchemy to fetch the all the results in a single `JOIN` query.

If configuring the relationship is undesirable, you could issue a query specifying the option:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload
from sqlmodel import select

    ...
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        parent = Parent()
        session.add(parent)
        await session.commit()
        result = await session.scalars(
            select(Parent).options(selectinload(Parent.children))
        )
        parent = result.first()
        print(
            parent.children_count
        )  # I need 0 here, as of now this parent has no children
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @snakecharmerb, this works, if I add `sa_relationship_kwargs={'lazy': 'selectin'}` to my model, do I have to run alembic and create a migration script, the current table is configured without the `sa_relationship_kwargs`?

Comment: Relationship exist entirely in the Python layer, so there should be no need for a migration.

Comment: I have the same problem.i add "sa_relationship_kwargs={'lazy':'selectin'} in my model,use select(model).where(model.id==id).options(selectinload(model.children).i got same error,greenlet_spawn has not been called! how to fix it? this my problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74835091/use-asyncsession-sqlalchemy-errorsqlalchemy-exc-missinggreenlet-greenlet-spawn

Answer (score 4):

The main reason for this error is that in the synchronous `sqlalchemy` driver you can use the `session` for the lazy loading queries properly. Assume you have two relational models to each other, fetch the parent by a query then you are going to reach the child leading to another query (i.e. lazy loading). However, when you are using the async driver on top of `sqlalchemy` (e.g. `asyncpg`) the session will be automatically closed each time after a query leading to the raising error for getting the child info.

Therefore, generally, to solve this, you can adopt the different loading strategies (eager loading) whether in the **relationship** or in the **query**:

##### Relationship

You should add `lazy= "joined" or "selectin"` in the relationship

```py
class Parent(Base):
    ...
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent", lazy="selectin")
```

In this way, you can now perform the query in your crud method as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

async def create_parent(db: AsyncSession) -> Parent:
    parent = Parent()
    db.add(parent)
    await db.commit()
    await db.refresh(parent)  # you need this
    print(parent.children_count)  # works properly now
    return parent
```

<sub>Note: the async db session has been injected as a parameter to the crud method.</sub>

---

##### Query

Now, let's say we haven't changed the relationship lazy value, so we would need those same changes into the query as follows:

Using `joinedload`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, selectinload

async def create_parent(db: AsyncSession) -> Parent:
    parent = Parent()
    db.add(parent)
    await db.commit()

    result = await db.execute(
        select(Parent)
        .options(joinedload(Parent.children))
        .where(Parent.id == parent.id)
    )
    parent = result.scalars().unique().one()

    print(parent.children_count)  # works properly now

    return parent
```

Or using `selectin`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, selectinload

async def create_parent(db: AsyncSession) -> Parent:
    parent = Parent()
    db.add(parent)
    await db.commit()

    result = await db.scalars(
        select(Parent)
        .options(selectinload(Parent.children))
        .where(Parent.id == parent.id)
    )
    parent = result.first()

    print(parent.children_count)  # works properly now

    return parent
```

---

[**Loading Strategy Differences**]:

> `joinedload` is used which performs an SQL JOIN to load the related `Parent.children` objects. This means all data is loaded in one go. It results in fewer database round-trips, but the initial load might be slower due to the join operation.

> `selectinload` strategy breaks up the loading into two separate queries — one for the parent and one for the child objects. This can sometimes be faster than joinedload as it avoids complex joins.

---

<sub>PS: I used `sqlalchemy` form instead of `sqlmodel`</sub>

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was due to a misleading error message. To me this error had nothing to do with a failed to spawn greenlet worker and that I had an invalid query where my relationships were misconfigured.

How I was able to debug this was first adding this line to my main method:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()    
logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

By adding this line sqlalchemy will output your generated database query logs making it easier to see which table failed.

Then I checked every single nested relationship I had using this line and cross referencing it with [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many):

```
await session.execute(select(<TableName>))
```

For many to many relationships I also needed to add:

```
relationship(secondary="junction_table_name", lazy="subquery")
```

I chose subquery more for performance reasons but you can make a more informed choice here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship

I went through the rabbit hole of joins and using selectinload, joinedload, contains_eager all of which did not solve the problem. This is my conjecture but what caused the problem is that a failed query tried to write an error the the IO stream which caused an error in the greenlet worker.