# How do I display all of the customers's related addresses?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I can't get all the addresses associated with the customer.

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    authorization_token = Column(String, nullable=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    surname = Column(String, nullable=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=True)
    telephone = Column(String, nullable=True)

    addresses = relationship("Address", secondary="customer_address", back_populates="customer")

    async def to_dict(self):
        return {"id": self.id, 
                "authorization_token": self.authorization_token, 
                "name": self.name, 
                "surname": self.surname, 
                "email": self.email, 
                "telephone": self.telephone, 
                "addresses": [address.to_dict() for address in self.addresses] }

class CustomerAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer_address"

    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("customer.id"), primary_key=True)
    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"), primary_key=True)

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    city_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("city.id"), nullable=True)
    street = Column(String, nullable=True)
    house = Column(String, nullable=True)
    floor = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    entrance = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    apartment = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

    customer = relationship("Customer", secondary="customer_address", back_populates="addresses")

    async def to_dict(self):
        return {"id": self.id, 
                "city_id": self.city_id, 
                "street": self.street, 
                "house": self.house, 
                "floor": self.floor, 
                "entrance": self.entrance, 
                "apartment": self.apartment}

async def get_customer_by_id(customer_id: int, session: AsyncSession = async_db_session) -> dict:
    customer = select(Customer).where(Customer.id == customer_id)
    customer = await session.execute(customer)
    customer = customer.scalars().first()
    if not customer:
        return {'error': 'No customer found with the specified ID'}
    customer = await customerto_dict()
    return customer.to_dict()
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncAdapt_asyncpg_cursor._prepare_and_execute' was never awaited
```

The error is related to this line:

```
"addresses": [address.to_dict() for address in self.addresses]
```

Is it possible to retrieve data using a single query (asynchronous version of SQLAlchemy)?

What I haven't tried.)

The code above, one of the 5 versions, but the error(s) is caused by wanting to get data from "two" linked tables (method to_dict()).

My goal is to get: {"id": id,
"authorization_token": token,
"name": name
...
"addresses": [
{"id": id,
"city_id": city},
{"id": id,
"city_id": city}
]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MissingGreenlet: greenlet\_spawn has not been called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252768/missinggreenlet-greenlet-spawn-has-not-been-called)

Comment: If the suggested duplicate does not solve your problem, please fix the code in the question which (1) doesn't include the line that fails (2) references a customer model that is not defined (3) isn't correctly indented. Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: The solution is the same as the duplicate: pass `lazy='selectin'` to `Customer.addresses` and do `await address.to_dict()...` in `Customer.to_dict()`.