# How do you establish a self-referencing foreign key in SQLAlchemy 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

Here is my model:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'

    id          : Mapped[int]       = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    given_id    : Mapped[str]       = mapped_column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=True)
    cancel_id   : Mapped[int]       = mapped_column(ForeignKey('model.given_id'), nullable=True)
    return_model: Mapped['MyModel'] = relationship(remote_side=[given_id])
```

With the structure like above when calling `return_model` I'm getting the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

But if I replace `given_id` with `id` then everything works fine and `MyModel` is able to reference itself:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'

    id          : Mapped[int]       = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    given_id    : Mapped[str]       = mapped_column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=True)
    cancel_id   : Mapped[int]       = mapped_column(ForeignKey('model.id'), nullable=True)
    return_model: Mapped['MyModel'] = relationship(remote_side=[id])
```

What is the right way of self-referencing in `SQLAlchemy 2.0`? How to achieve a one-to-one relationship? What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I'm using async engine.

Comment: This looks like an error caused by unexpected IO in async code -does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74256068/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: Yes it was about lazy loading. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured it out. When accessing related object/s the lazy loading will take place. According to the documentation:

> in order to succeed will usually emit IO to the database, which will fail under asyncio as no implicit IO is allowed.

The suggested solution is for the `Base` model to inherit from `AsyncAttrs`:

```
class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

> This mixin adds a single new attribute AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs to all classes, which will yield the value of any attribute as an awaitable. This allows attributes which may be subject to lazy loading or deferred / unexpiry loading to be accessed such that IO can still be emitted

and now I can access my related object:

```
result = await instance.awaitable_attrs.return_model
```