# Why doesn't SQLAlchemy's fetchall() method return attributes associated with table fields?

Tags: python, async-await, sqlalchemy, fastapi, attributeerror

I'm trying to retrieve data from a `PostgreSQL` table using `SQLAlchemy` and `FastAPI` (*async*). This is my model:

```
class LoginHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'login_history'

    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False
    )
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='login_history')
    user_agent = Column(String(255))
    login_dt = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, user_id: UUID, user_agent: str, login_dt: datetime) -> None:
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.login_dt = login_dt
        self.user_agent = user_agent
```

Below is a snippet from the user service:

```
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Header, Request
from sqlalchemy import insert, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

from auth.src.models.entity import LoginHistory

async def get_login_history(
    authorization: Annotated[str, Header()],
    db: AsyncSession
) -> dict:
    result = await token_logic.get_token_authorization(authorization)
    if result.get('error'):
        return result
    access_token = result.get('token')
    user_id = await token_logic.get_user_id_by_token(access_token)
    query = select(LoginHistory).where(LoginHistory.user_id == user_id)
    history = await db.execute(query)
    login_history = history.fetchall()
    return {'success': [{
            'user_agent': record.user_agent,
            'login_dt': record.login_dt.isoformat()
    } for record in login_history]
    }
```

When I make a request, I get an error: `AttributeError: user_agent`. As far as I understand, the `fetchall()` method should return a list of `Row` objects containing attributes associated with the table fields (in my case, `user_agent`, `login_dt` etc.). What do I do wrong? I appreciate your replies very much.

Versions I'm using: `SQLAlchemy==2.0.16`, `FastAPI==0.97.0`, `asyncpg==0.27.0`.

Comment: Have you tried doing things like printing what is in the variables at different stages in the code - that would be my first port of call - see where things aren't adhering to your assumptions. Could login_history for example be None?

Comment: Fetchall can also return None - it's an Optional List

Comment: Did you add the `user_agent` column to your model after the table had been originally created?

Comment: @JGFMK, no it can't. Login_history does contain a single row so far. The printed out content of the variable 'history' is `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult object at 0x000002509B5DC350>`. When I try to print out 'login-history', it throws the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?`

Comment: @snakecharmerb, no, the column 'user_agent' had been added to the model before the table was originally created.

Comment: @JGFMK, I added more rows to the table `login_history`, the result's the same. By the way, the method `first()` works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252768/missinggreenlet-greenlet-spawn-has-not-been-called

Comment: @JGFMK, thank you very much for the link, it was helpful. As far as I got it, the problem was in using `relationship()` in my model, so I would need to use `selectinload` in my query. But I chose another option: I changed my query so that only fields that I need are selected: `query = select(LoginHistory.user_agent, LoginHistory.login_dt).where(LoginHistory.user_id == user_id)`. Thus I avoided selection of the one-to-one related field `user`. Everything worked. Thank you again for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.fetchall()` is returning a list of single-element tuples, where each element is an instance of `LoginHistory`:

```py
[
    (<__main__.LoginHistory object at 0x7f43764f7590>,),
    (<__main__.LoginHistory object at 0x7f43764f7610>,)
]
```

so `record.user_Agent for record in login_history` will fail because the tuples do not have a `useragent` attribute.

Calling `.scalars()` rather than `.fetchall()` will fix the problem, because the purpose of `.scalars()` is precisely to eliminate the wrapper tuples from the result. Or we can simply do

```py
login_history = await session.scalars(query)
```

and remove the redundant `history` variable.